# .Net linebot isRock.LineBot.Utility.PushMessage doesn't work

Tags: c#, line

I built a linebot with LineBotSDK and deployed on Azure application.
It ran nice before but when I revise some code and push it today, I found isRock.LineBot.Utility.PushMessage() can't be used and with no exception.
I've reinstall the API using Nuget but still can't resolve this problem.
Is there any solution to deal with it?

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found why isRock.LineBot.Utility.PushMessage() can't work.
Cause Line has limitation of push message per month. 
So the solution is to upgrade the account....